# Is there a Gradle plugin equivalent of “mvn dependency:analyze”?

Tags: maven, gradle, maven-plugin, gradle-plugin

I want to analyze my project dependencies.Is there a Gradle plugin equivalent to

```
mvn dependency:analyze
```

which will analyzes the dependencies of this project and produces a report that summarizes which are: used and declared; used and undeclared; unused and declared

Answer (score 0):

There is a [gradle-dependency-analyze](https://github.com/wfhartford/gradle-dependency-analyze) plugin you can try to use. It analyses your project dependencies and fails a build if dependencies are declared but not used or used but not declared.

You can declare it as follows:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'ca.cutterslade.gradle:gradle-dependency-analyze:1.2.0'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'ca.cutterslade.analyze'
```

And run it via one of the tasks: `analyzeClassesDependencies`, `analyzeTestClassesDependencies` or `analyzeDependencies`.